# Most common row in binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have very large binary matrices with duplicated rows:

```
# create matrix
M = matrix(0, 10000, 50)

# randomly set up to two elements per row to one

for(ii in 1:nrow(M)){

M[ii, sample(1:ncol(M), 1)] = 1
M[ii, sample(1:ncol(M), 1)] = 1

}
```

I'm trying to find the index of the most frequently occuring row. The general problem of finding the most frequently occuring row is discussed for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538716/find-the-most-repeated-row-in-a-matrix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326184/identify-most-frequent-row-from-matrix). Another viable solution is to use `paste0`:

```
# string vector for each row
row_strings = apply(M, 1, paste0, collapse="")

# tabulate the strings
count_df    = data.frame(table(row_strings))

# get indices of most frequently occuring string
which(row_strings == count_df$row_strings[which.max(count_df$Freq)])
```

However, these solutions are either slow or (relatively) complicated. I was wondering whether there is a more convenient, fast solution for this problem for the special case of binary matrices?

Comment: Maybe convert row_strings to integer, then do lookup?

Comment: Maybe try : `unique_val <- do.call(paste0, data.frame(M))`,  `which(unique_val == names(sort(table(unique_val), decreasing = TRUE)[1]))` Logic is same as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coercing rows `toString` and `table` them.

```
ts <- apply(M, 1, toString)
pat <- names(sort(table(ts), decreasing=T)[1])
which(ts == pat)
# [1] 101 108 460 839 852
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- 1e3
n <- 10
set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(sample(0:1, m*n, prob=c(1-.5, .5), replace=T), m, n)
```